# DQL for selecting a row in a x-to-x relationship

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have 3 different entities that are mapped to each other. To give a very simplified example.

ProductList:

```
class ProductList
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="productlist") */
    protected $products;
}
```

Product:

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Edition")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="edition_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $edition;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductList")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="productlist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $productlist;
}
```

Edition

```
class Edition
{
    protected $id;
}
```

How can I get all the productLists in my productListRepository that contain only 1 product with an specific edition id using DQL?

I know how to do it the 'lazy' way by retrieving all the items from the productList and check whether the related product entity contains an specific edition id but this seems highly ineffective if there is a large dataset to iterate through.

I know I have to use a join but I am stuck at the idea that I need to iterate through the products in productLists. ProductLists can contain more then one products but I only need the ones with only a single product and check wether they have an edition with the specific id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for **extract all the productlist for a specified version that have only one edition**:

```
SELECT pl
FROM ProductList pl
-- LEFT JOIN pl.products p
LEFT JOIN p.edition e
WHERE (sum (p1) from Product p1 where  p1.productlist = pl.id) = 1
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you this does work! Is there a way to include a statement in the query so that only the productLists containing one item are fetched. Or should that logic be done outside the query?

Comment: ah! only the ProductList  with one  and only one Edition must match?

Comment: Exactly! Only the productLists that contain one product, and thus one edition, must be fetched.